# echarts make tooltip title bold

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, echarts

Is there any way to make the title (the "May 2021" text) in the echarts tooltips bold / bigger font size?

In the documentation, there's nothing mentioned.

Using the "hacky way" and updating the CSS can be a bit resource-intensive on the client-side as the tooltip is generated on each mouse move. - thus looking for a more clean solution.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Find the chart container, after find the coresponding div element, and from the inline CSS or javascript or Jquery change the font-weigth and font-size, but with text "!important" to override the existing css values.

If you paste the desired code here, I could help exatly with that code!

Comment: Thanks, the problem is the div is generated on every mouse move so updating the new div can be a bit resource-consuming on the client-side, I was looking for a more clean solution.

Comment: The div is not generated on every mouse move, just the Text and the css transform value, where the popup to be showed. If you use CSS is not a client-side consuming.

Comment: I've added a screenshot with the code

Comment: css:
div[style="font-size:14px;color:#666;font-weight:400;line-height:1;"] {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

jquery:
$('.card-body echart-line-total-sales').children('div:nth-child(2)').children().children().children().css({'font-size': '20px', 'font-weight': 'bold'});

or if you can add an ID or a CLASS to that dom, that would be better for selector

Answer (score 0):

I found an example in the documentation that is using html for the tooltip, and it's as simple as writing html directly in the formatter.

```
formatter: function (param) {
  const data = param.data;
  return [
   '<span class="fs-mini me-2">VBP_PERIOD:</span><b class="text-blue">' + param.seriesName + '</b><hr size=1 style="margin: 3px 0">',
   '<span class="fs-mini me-2">Media_Volume:</span><b class="text-blue">' + data[0].toLocaleString() + '</b><br/>',
  ].join('')
}
```

https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=doc-example%2Fcandlestick-axisPointer&edit=1&reset=1